# Delphi calculate TStream hash/checksum

Tags: delphi

i'm looking for a fast way for calculate a checksum of TStream (TMemoryStream). The purpose is store the hash and use it for detect if the checksum is changenged after some operation.

this is my code:

```
function GetChecksum(const Stream: TStream): String;
var 
  MD5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  MD5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
      Result := MD5.HashStreamAsHex(Stream);
  finally
      MD5.Free;
  end;
end;
```

it works, but with a huge stream is a bit slow.

There is a fast way for calculate a stream checksum?

Comment: *"but with a huge stream is a bit slow"* - what is "slow" and why do you *think* it is slow? as compared to what?

Comment: @MBo thanks System.Hash.THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue is perfect

Comment: @ar099968 OK, so I transform comment to answer

Comment: Indy has other hash classes avaliable, but just MD5, perhaps CRC16 or CRC32 will suit your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code calculates MD5 - it is cryptographic hash, rather complex and slow.

For checksum you can try simpler algorithms like `BobJenkinsHash` (S[ystem.Hash.THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Hash.THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue)).

Also you can check performance of [Spring4d](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/src/master/) and [DCPCrypt](https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/dcpcrypt2010/src/default/) implementations of MD5